# Flutter stripe_payment Native pay not charged(Apple Pay and Google Pay)

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, applepay

**The stripe payment API call return status 200 but the amount isn't charged.**

I have a Flutter application uses Stripe payment.

I have done:

1. certification has been created.
2. merchant id has been created.

Followed the example of `stripe_payment`, I have my native payment method below:

```
void _handleNativePayment(String amount) async {
    Token token = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithNativePay(
      androidPayOptions: AndroidPayPaymentRequest(
        totalPrice: amount,
        currencyCode: _currencyCode,
      ),
      applePayOptions: ApplePayPaymentOptions(
        countryCode: _countryCode,
        currencyCode: _currencyCode,
        items: [
          ApplePayItem(
            type: 'final',
            label: _paymentLabel,
            amount: amount,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

    await StripePayment.completeNativePayRequest();
}
```

When I run it on simulator, I can see the payment is done and can view the request on Stripe dashboard unfortunately the Payment is still 0.:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before look into the code, please make sure you have finished the following steps:
0. stripe_payment is added.

1. Merchant Id has been created.
2. Apple Pay has been enabled in Xcode.
3. Stripe "Standard Key" and "Restricted Key" have been generated.

   - standard key contains publishable key and secret key
   - publishable key uses in Flutter project.
   - restricted key uses in **Server side**.

What i have been done for the native payment:

1. calls paymentRequestWithNativePay() to get token.
2. charges with own implemented charge method(on Server side, makes sure you use the restricted key and it has charge write permission).
3. calls paymentRequestWithNativePay()

```
    void handleNativePayment(BuildContext context, String amountInStr) async {
        // I used environment configurations for ANDROID_PAY_MODE, use "test" in test mode
        // and uses "production" in production mode
        StripePayment.setOptions(StripeOptions(
            publishableKey: _publishableKey,
            merchantId: _merchantId,
            androidPayMode: EnvironmentConfig.ANDROID_PAY_MODE,
        ));
    
        // this is my service class talks to server side API 
        PaymentService paymentService = Provider.of<PaymentService>(
          context,
          listen: false,
        );
    
        Token token = await StripePayment.paymentRequestWithNativePay(
          androidPayOptions: AndroidPayPaymentRequest(
            totalPrice: amountInStr,
            currencyCode: _currencyCode,
          ),
          applePayOptions: ApplePayPaymentOptions(
            countryCode: _countryCode,
            currencyCode: _currencyCode,
            items: [
              ApplePayItem(
                type: 'final',
                label: paymentLabel,
                amount: amountInStr,
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
    
        // converts amount from string to int, and it is in cents
        dynamic chargeResult = await paymentService.charge({
          "token": token.tokenId,
          "amount": double.parse(amountInStr) * 100,
          "currency": _currencyCode,
        });
    
        if (chargeResult is ChargeResult) {
          _buildSnackBar(context, "Payment success", Colors.green);
        } else {
          _buildSnackBar(context, "Payment fail", Colors.red);
        }
    
        await StripePayment.completeNativePayRequest();
      }

  _buildSnackBar(BuildContext context, String content, Color color) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(content),
      backgroundColor: color,
    );
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
```

Here's the PaymentService in Flutter. You need implement the server side charge API call with the Stripe restricted key.

```
class PaymentService {
  var logger = Logger(printer: PrettyPrinter());

  Future<dynamic> charge(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> charge = {
      "source": data["token"],
      "amount": data["amount"],
      "currency": data["currency"],
    };
    final response = await DioHttp.post('/stripe/payment/charge', charge);
    if (response.containsKey("results")) {
      return ChargeResult.fromMap(response["results"]);
    } else {
      String errorMessage = response["errors"][0]["description"];
      return errorMessage;
    }
  }
}
```

There's one more thing needs your attention:

When test with Android phone, don't use Stripe test cards numbers, it always gives you request failure(error codeOR-CCSEH-21). What you need to do is:

1. sets android pay mode to 'test'.
2. pays with your own/real card and it will pass(In below attached payment records, you can see the last payment contains my name, that's because i used my own card for the android google pay testing)

Hope it helps developers who needs it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Were you able to put it into production?
I Have an ERROR: Request Failed - Unexpected developer error, please try again later.
My question is: in merchantId (Google Pay MerchantId or Stripe MerchantId).
And where I inform Google Pay, the integration with Stripe, Google Pay has already authorized my application for production.
The documentation is not clear about the steps to put into production.